# Does anyome know why I am receiving the following error?: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Hi guys is am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'
```

The traceback looks like this:

```
AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-dfcbcabe20ea> in <module>()
      2  for name, df in all_data.items():
      3  top_10 = df.mean().dropna().sort_values().iloc[-10]
----> 4  top_10_columns[name] = top_10.index
```

While running the following code:

```
top_10_columns = {}
for name, df in all_data.items():
    top_10 = df.mean().dropna().sort_values().iloc[-10]
    top_10_columns[name] = top_10.index
```

Comment: ``.iloc[-10]`` would return single value not series, ``print(top_10)``.

Comment: I agree with @sushanth. Print out the value and/or its type to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accidentally not getting the "top 10" items when you do `.iloc[-10]`, but just the 10th to last item. So `top_10` is a single value of type `numpy.float64`. Giving `iloc` a range should fix it. `.iloc[0:10]` or `.iloc[-10:]` depending on whether your sort is ascending or descending and you want to get either the first ten items (`.iloc[0:10]`) or the last ten items (`.iloc[-10:]`).

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up with. Thnx!

    top_10_columns = {}
    for name, df in all_data.items():
        top_10 = df.mean().dropna().sort_values().iloc[-10:]
        top_10[name] = top_10.index

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to an array, but Python is interpreting top_10_columns as a float. Above your for loop you must declare it as an array i.e top_10_columns = []

Comment: I appreciate it - I had the dictionary brackets { }

Comment: Good to know, I always start with the small stuff. Glad you found your answer though!